# SQL Find first occurrence of row in table

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
id name marks 
1;"mohit";10
2;"mohit";20
3;"raj";30
4;"rupesh";40
5;"rupesh";50
```

Expected output is :

```
1;"mohit";10
4;"rupesh";40
```

Comment: Why no raj in the result?

Comment: There is no such thing as "the first row" of a table. That term only makes sense if you supply a sort order when retrieving the rows. Based on which value should the row be selected? id? marks? Something else?

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM Your_Table
WHERE ID IN (
             SELECT Min(ID)
             FROM Your_Table
             GROUP BY Name
             HAVING Count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!! Please provide an optimum/efficient solution

Answer (score 1):

I think `DISTINCT ON` should work here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name) name, id, marks
FROM your_table
ORDER BY name, id;
```

This assumes that you want the first row of each person with regard to the `id`.

[image]

### Demo

**Late Edit:**

It looks like you want the first record from each name group where a name appears at least two or more times.  We can try the following query:

```
SELECT id, name, marks
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id) rn,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name) cnt
    FROM your_table
) t
WHERE rn = 1 AND cnt > 1;
```

Comment: Its returning 'raj' row as well

Comment: Why should `raj` not appear in the result set?  You never gave us any logic for this.  From what we could see, your expected output just has a typo in it.

Comment: Thanks. @Tim, I clearly mentioned the expected result. The question was asked by interviewer to me.

Comment: @RupeshPatil You didn't clearly explain your requirement, but I have given you an option in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

USE GROUP BY TO COUNT MULTIPLE OCCURENCE..

SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IN(
SELECT name FROM table 
GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(name) > 1)

Comment: This will return both mohit rows, and both rupesh rows.

Comment: try to use SELECT TOP 1 *.. however group by will alphabetically arrange the name before selecting the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
select * from 
(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
    PARTITION BY name
    ORDER BY id ) as rnum , name ,id ,marks
from  your_table) A
where rnum = 1
```